# Paypal Payment Button with Callback

Tags: php, paypal

I'd like to use a PayPal ExpressCheckout button on my website. The problem is, the standard button won't work for me because I need a callback. Does anyone know how to do this (in php)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your Paypal account and enable ipn. Then setup an ipn to process info submitted with the button.